# How to overwrite environment variables in mac using Shell Script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, environment-variables

I have a set of environment variables that need to be set on the basis of the arguments specified in the shell script. 
But the problem is that those variables are already defined in the bash profile
FOR EXAMPLE:

bash_profile has a variable called "KARAN":
export KARAN=/config/1

Now on running the shell script, this is what it should do:
export KARAN=/config/2 (Changed the bash profile's KARAN value to 2)

Comment: You have to source the file; executing the script in a separate process cannot affect the environment of the parent process.

Comment: @chepner I can source the file after the overwriting of variables is done

Comment: @trojanfoe Please make me understand how is it not about programming

Comment: Shell scripting is certainly borderline as it does contain programming logic etc, however this question appears to be more sysadmin-related.

Comment: This does contain shell scripting mainly - to be specific - mainly the commands 'sed' and 'awk' should be helpful in this case.

Comment: I don't see anything about `sed` or `awk` in the question so that is not relevant.

Comment: `sed` can be used to modify the environment variables inside the bash profile depending upon the script arguments, but I am facing some error in doing so.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to write a script to modify `$HOME/.profile`? Or are you trying to do something else - either in addition or instead?

Comment: I was trying to modify env variables already existing inside the bash_profile. But it seems that using multiple profiles is a much more effective way to handle it. The question is pretty straightforward

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## You can create a new Profile with all the new definitions. and then call the line below on top of your shell script. Similarly, you can create as many profiles as you want and use it.

```
    source bash_profile_new
```

Comment: Tried this, but when I sourced the new bash_profile, the env variables still were the same, i.e. unmodified

Comment: did you redefine all the environmental variables in new bash_profile?

Comment: Yes, I added all the env variables and modified those which were needed.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working for you, it is working fine for me . 

  sranjan:utility_scrtips sranjan$ source ~/.bash_profile
  sranjan:sandip_work sranjan$ echo $JAVA_HOME
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home
  sranjan:utility_scrtips sranjan$ source bash_profile_new
  sranjan:utility_scrtips sranjan$ echo $JAVA_HOME
  /Library/Java/Home
  sranjan:utility_scrtips sranjan$
  sranjan:utility_scrtips sranjan$ cat bash_profile_new
  export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
  sranjan:utility_scrtips sranjan$

Comment: I achieved it using multiple bash profiles. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @KaranMehta so the solution I suggested worked right?

Comment: The goal was to overwrite the variables in the same bash_profile but what we achieved was making a new bash_profile and defining the variables there again. So it is kind of a different approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. If your script needs to set the env var to a specific value just do so using `export VAR=val`. What I think you're asking is how to have a script modify the environment of the current shell. And that is impossible without the cooperation of both shells. That is because environment vars are inherited by child processes. But a child process cannot directly modify the environment of its parent process (or some other random process for that matter). To do so the two processes must coordinate the exchange of data. This is typically done by using the `source` command if the child process is a shell script. Or by having the child process write a series of `export` statements to stdout and having the parent shell capture and execute those statements. For example, let's say I have a script named `set_env` that looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
echo export KARAN=/config_2
echo export VAR2=val2
```

The current shell would then do

```
eval $(set_env)
```

Note, however, `eval` is dangerous. I prefer to do this which is slightly safer:

```
set_env | source /dev/stdin
```

That, however, only works in shells like ksh and zsh. Due to how bash handles pipelines the `source` is actually executed in a child shell and therefore the vars won't be set in the current shell.

Comment: The question is clearer as ever. I want to modify env variables that are already defined inside the bash_profile, and I achieved that using multiple profiles and `source`-ing them based on conditional statements.